# Installing MySQL on freebsd

Tags: mysql, freebsd

I have a server running Freebsd 6.3, and I'm trying to install mysql-server.

I went to the `/ports/databases/mysql51-server` directory and did:

```
make
make install
```

And everything seemed to go smooth. MySQL was not running, so I tried `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server start`
and this command returned, but there still is no MySQL server running.

I tried to verify this two ways:

```
telnet localhost 3306
```

and

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable MySQL in rc.conf; add `mysql_enable="YES"` to the file.

Then run `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server start` again.